# Can't boot my Htc Wildfire S after deleting Sense

Tags: boot, htc-wildfire-s

I wanted to free up some internal space.
So I decided to delete some pre-installed apps.
Then I accidently removed an app called HtcSense.apk.
As I rebooted it didn't manage to start anymore.

I would assume I could download the app from somewhere, but how will I be able to put it back on my phone?

Comment: Can you see your status bar with blank area below it?

Comment: no, I cant boot at all. I can only go to the bootloader.

Comment: I assume your bootloader is unlocked then -- you'll need to flash firmware to restore it, unless you have a custom recovery that will let you remount `/system` as RW via ADB so you can push the file over.

Comment: @MatthewRead, I have managed to install a custom recovery on my phone. The problem is, which files have I deleted?

Comment: I assume you're using a custom ROM as you were able to delete pre-installed apps.  If this is the case, have you considered simply re-installing the ROM?  Unless you provide more details on what actually happens instead of *a clean boot*, it'll be difficult for anyone to even begin diagnosing which files you deleted to cause these issues.

Comment: I am actually not installed a custom ROM. I am not sure how i could install a Rom on my Device. I have a HTC wildfire S and the bootloader is unlocked and it is rooted.

Comment: Not so scold you or anything, but most of the explanations for rooting a device and unlocking the bootloader include steps on installing a custom bootloader and taking a Nandroid Backup.  Have you taken one?  If not, there may still be hope.  On a site like xda-developers there may be a community of users who have the stock images for your phone.  If so, you can take these and hopefully restore your phone to the way it was when you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally fixed my phone. Thank you @Matthew Read @ctt for your help!!!:) I am really sorry that I asked more then one question about this. I was just panicking that my phone wasn't working.

I have managed to install a custom rom to my Htc Wildfire S. [This](http://cm7-wildfire-s.googlecode.com/files/unofficial-CM-7.2-RC1-marvel-nigthly-03_12_2012.zip) is the rom I used.

I had to to a factory reset and I had to delete all the cache.

Thanks again for all your support! :)

Comment: Glad to know it's fixed..