# What .apk is missing for my htc wilfire s to be able to boot?

Tags: htc, apk, delete, htc-wildfire-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't boot my Htc Wildfire S after deleting Sense](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21520/cant-boot-my-htc-wildfire-s-after-deleting-sense)

I have deleted some pre installed apps on my Htc Wildfire S.
Now I am not able to start it, does anyone know which .apk could be missing and is causing it to not boot?